# What could cause a successful bound Send Email action to not be received?

Tags: email, office365, action, power-automate

I'm building a flow that (When Case is Created or Modified)-> gets a Case record -> creates an Email record -> sends that email via a bound action.

When I run the flow, it succeeds, and a row is added to the Email table. The status of the email is Sent, with the To Recipients as my email,

[image]

HOWEVER, the email doesn't show up in my inbox. I've checked my spam folder, my company's quarantine folder, and I don't have any other ideas where this email could be.

[image]

[image]

In the add row action, the only other fields I fill in is Description, From (Created By primary email), and Subject.

---

Secondary, unrelated Flow question: I'm trying to set the Regarding (Case) field, and I can't figure out the correct syntax. The Internet is all over the place on that one. I get a `URL was not parsed due to an ODataUnrecognizedPathException. Resource not found for the segment provided in the URL.` error when I try any one of a number of combinations:

```
cases(CASE UUID)
/cases(CASE UUID)
/cases/(CASE UUID)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issueSend field should be Yes in order to actually send the email.